# converting XML to specific XML schema?

Tags: json, xml, xsd, schema

Sorry but I am not knowledgeable about XML at all, although I do code in HTML, CSS, and a little jQuery.

I have an API that outputs JSON data, that I need to transfer over to a specific XML schema. I have found a JSON to XML converter, but it does not convert to the specific XML format that I need. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Just to note, the XML schema file provided to me is `.XSD`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to define the transformation in an .xslt file in order to convert. It is not possible to create the required .xslt transformation file automatically (except for simple and trivial cases) from an analysis of the .xsd file. They are two different things completely.

You can solve your problem in two steps:

Step 1: Understand the transformations needed and manually create the required .xslt file. Here is a good tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html

Step 2: Directly transform your JSON data to the desired XML using your .xslt file as described here https://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2007/07/05/transforming-json/

OR

Create an intermediate .xml file from the JSON data and transform the intermediate .xml file to the desired .xml output file using the .xslt you created, a fairly straightforward task.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a big help.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Ryan Keene you're welcome, please feel free to accept the answer if your problem was solved.

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted, maybe some of the more experienced SO'ers could explain?

Comment: @PranayPalni This question is currently in the close vote due to being very low quality. If you answer low quality questions that have a high chance of getting closed, you might get downvotes from users since you're encouraging low quality questions (for more questions see meta.stackoverflow).

Comment: @runDOSrun Thanks, that makes a lot of sense! :)